# Why Laravel Vite doesn't build Tailwind CSS for PC when deployed to host?

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm facing a weird issue, after I deploy Laravel app to Heroku servers, my website on phone looks nice and Tailwind is working, but if I open it on PC, there's no styling. What can cause this?

Not sure if it's allowed to post links here, so for now I won't

Comment: +1 I have the same issue. I can test locally and it builds, but when pushed to Heroku the styling is off. I've added build packs and ""heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"" to package.json

Comment: @Colin I tried many things and now Vite is being built, but it takes for a while till it get's done, try browsing through different routes and styling might appear, if no I can give you my package.json and buildpacks I set for Heroku